# Android displays text in wrong encoding after update to Java 8

Tags: android, android-studio, encoding, utf-8, java-8

I've updated my project to SDK version 24 and Java 8 and encountered a strange encoding issue.

By some strange reason Android treats my hardcoded UTF-8 strings as Windows-1251 and thus the text is garbled.

Like this:

[image]

This is what I changed:

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

compileOptions {
    encoding = 'utf-8'
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

And what I've tried:

- changed encoding in Android Studio settings
- added compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251' and compileOptions.encoding
  = 'utf-8'
- added system variable JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:-Dfile.encoding=UTF8

If I revert back to Java 7 everything is ok.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you use the jack compiler ?

Comment: I used 
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        } in build.gradle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in Jack compiler, have a look at this [post](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=218892).

Jack has been using the default VM encoding, which on windows is windows-1252. So, your text is encoded with `UTF-8` and decoded with `windows-1252` by Jack compiler, and this is why they became garbled.

Until now, `Gradle Plugin` doesn't support an API to set the decode format, so we need to wait...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in Windows(but not Mac OSX). this line solve my problem(put it in `gradle.properties` of your project):

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

note that this part change encoding:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```