# Messed up encoding with Jack Compiler

Tags: android, encoding, jack-compiler

After enabling `Jack Options` i can't print a `String` with special characters such as the euro sign (€) or Greek letters.I've tried to change encoding to `UTF-8` with no luck.Any suggestions?Disabling Jack Options solves the problem, but i need Java 8 support.

```
String str="€";
byte[] arrByte = new byte[0];

    try {
        arrByte = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    System.out.println(new String(arrByte));
```

Comment: Did you try using &euro;? (it might need to be in strings.xml instead of hardcoded, so it gets evaluated)

Comment: Using unicode values solves the problem but since i have a long text with different characters that's not very convenient

Answer (score 0):

I added the following line, as was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514276/android-displays-text-in-wrong-encoding-after-update-to-java-8), in gradle.properties and the encoding seems to be fixed now.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```